# How to run some tests only in azure devops CI env but not locally

Tags: c#, azure-devops, xunit.net

I would like to specify some long-running c# project xUnit tests to only run in azure devops CI pipeline, but not when a click 'Run All' in Visual Studio locally (vs2019). Is there a 'best practice' for this kind of behaviour?

I played around with making a test playlist and running that locally instead of `Run All`, but that would require updating the list (or lists) everytime i add new tests and this is error-prone.

Comment: Leo: I ended up with Ruben's solution, making a custom `FactAttribute` class that sets `Skip` property if `TF_BUILD` is not set in environment. DRY, does not hide tests from explorer and expresses intent cleanly.

Comment: If you want to solve this for **NUnit** rather than **xUnit**, see over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62388204/how-to-run-some-nunit-tests-only-in-azure-devops-ci-env-but-not-locally?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `Skip` property in `FactAttribute` is overridable - you can make a `FactWhenAttribute` and have it check an environment variable

Example in [this post from @Joseph Woodward](https://josephwoodward.co.uk/2019/01/skipping-xunit-tests-based-on-runtime-conditions)

> ```
> public sealed class IgnoreOnAppVeyorLinuxFact : FactAttribute
> {
>     public IgnoreOnAppVeyorLinuxFact() {
>         if(RuntimeInformation.IsOSPlatform(OSPlatform.Linux) && IsAppVeyor()) {
>             Skip = "Ignore on Linux when run via AppVeyor";
>         }
>     }
>
>     private static bool IsAppVeyor()
>         => Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("APPVEYOR") != null;
> }
> ```

Comment: Ah, this combined with Sebastian's answer would be a clean solution!

Answer (score 7):

AzureDevOps defines some [environment variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#system-variables). I would use `TF_BUILD` in conjunction with Ruben Bartelinks answer.

> Set to True if the script is being run by a build task.
>
> This variable is agent-scoped. It can be used as an environment variable in a script and as a parameter in a build task, but not as part of the build number or as a version control tag.

Comment: This is working well. Getting the value with a `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TF_BUILD")` and comparing it to "True" does separate execution environment from Azure DevOps pipeline and others.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your build pipeline is building using the `Release` build configuration and not using the `Debug` build config, you could use the `#IF !DEBUG` preprocessor directive arround your `[Fact]` attribute.

For example:

```
#if !DEBUG
[Fact]
#endif
public void YourTestMethod()
{
}
```