# How to run some NUnit tests only in azure devops CI env but not locally

Tags: c#, azure-devops, nunit

Identical to this: [How to run some tests only in azure devops CI env but not locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56593334/how-to-run-some-tests-only-in-azure-devops-ci-env-but-not-locally), but for NUnit, rather than xUnit.

I want some of my test to get run by my Azure DevOps pipeline, but not by my local (VisualStudio + R#) IDE.

Linked question solves this with a custom xUnit Attribute, but my project uses NUnit so answers to that question won't help.

Answer (score 0):

- Extend `NUnitAttribute` and `IApplyToTest(Test test)` to create a custom attribute that will allow you to control whether or not a particular test is run.
- In your implementation of `ApplyToTest`, use `new IgnoreAttribute("Blah").ApplyToTest(Test test)` to ignore the test (if applicable).

  - *`IgnoreAttribute.ApplyToTest()` is not virtual so you can't safely derive from `IgnoreAttribute` and `override` the method. Safer to use this composition instead.*
- Use `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` to determine whether or not to skip the test, by checking whether a particular Environment variable is defined (either one you define yourself, or one of the auto-defined variables that AzureDevOps defines, e.g. `TF_BUILD`)

  - *I found it convenient to check for any of the Environment Variables from `.Machine`, `.User` or `.Process`. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41410599/1662268*